# How to add multiple random effects? [Python, Statsmodel]

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels, mixed-models

I've been walking through the amazing [tutorial on mixed models](https://www.kaggle.com/ojwatson/mixed-models) in python using the statsmodel libary.

I've specified a model as such:

```
md = smf.mixedlm("Y~ X", df, groups=df["random"])
mdf = md.fit()
```

but now i want to add a second random variable. I thought it would be pretty straight forward, by just passing a `list` into my dataframe `df` as such:

```
md = smf.mixedlm("Y~ X", df, groups=df[["random1","random2"]])
mdf = md.fit()
```

But that doesn't work.

**How can I add a second random variable in my mixed model?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing it a list when you do:

```
groups=df[["random1","random2"]]
```

You're passing it a new data frame constructed of those two columns.

See:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('something.csv')

print(type(df['a']))

>>><class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print(type(df[['a', 'b']]))

>>><class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

print(type([df['a'], df['b']]))

>>><class 'list'>
```

If you look at the documentation for the mixedlm (https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.mixed_linear_model.MixedLM.html), you can see that the groups attribute only takes inputs that are 1d array like, which is why you can't pass it a data frame. The documentation also says:

> To include crossed random effects in a model, it is necessary to treat the entire dataset as a single group.

So you need to get the entire dataset into a structure that is 1D array like in order pass it a second random variable.

Comment: Anna, Please see this :D 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59359568/from-2d-to-1d-how-to-pass-a-second-random-effect-in-mixed-model-python-statsm