# From 2D to 1D, how to pass a second random effect in mixed model [Python, Statsmodel]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statsmodels

Building of this questions: [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57527535/how-to-add-multiple-random-effects-python-statsmodel)

let say i have a dataframe as such:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'y':[1.2,2.41,3.12,4.76],'x':['A','B'],'r1':['a','b','c','d'],'r2':['a2','b2','c2','d2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

y is a continuous variable. 
x is categorical and is the fixed component. It is binary. 
r1, r2 are categorical. They are the random components.

and i would pass it to the mixed model as such:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
md = smf.mixedlm("y ~ x", df, groups=df["r1"], re_formula="~ r1")
```

this works fine.

But NOW i want to add a second random variable, but that can only be done as a 1D array...
and i don't how to rearrange the data that i pass 2 variables to `groups`, as a 1D array

**Thus in summary**: How to rearrange the dataframe in such a way, so that i can pass 2 variables to `groups` as a 1D array? Please show the syntax for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you need `crossed random effects models`.

From the documentation:

> Statsmodels MixedLM handles most non-crossed random effects models,
>   and some crossed models. To include crossed random effects in a model,
>   it is necessary to treat the entire dataset as a single group. The
>   variance components arguments to the model can then be used to define
>   models with various combinations of crossed and non-crossed random
>   effects.

---

**Since you need a crossed model with no independent groups, you need to put everyone in the same group and specify the random effects using variance components.**

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                                        
import statsmodels.api as sm                                                                                               

d = {'y':[1,2,3,4],'x':[1,2,3,4],'r1':[1,2,3,4],'r2':[1,2,3,4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)                                                                                                          
df["group"] = 1    # all in the case group                                                                                                        

vcf = {"r1": "0 + C(r1)", "r2": "0 + C(r2)"}  # formula                                                        
model = sm.MixedLM.from_formula("y ~ x", groups="group",                                                    
                                vc_formula=vcf, re_formula="~r1", data=df)                                                   
result = model.fit()
```

Comment: wow! Thanks Makis. However i realize I made a mistake. The groups DO need to be independent. That is my x-variable (the fixed effect) is also category. I have changed it in the code. Does your answer still hold?

Comment: yes just make sure to modify accordingly your formula based on what you need. consider accepting and upvoting my answer. cheers

Comment: done and done! How would you modify the formula? And why add a column of "group" where everything = 1?

Comment: otherwise the current implementation will not work.